# Qt 5.15, ANGLE: use DirectComposition, i.e. Flip Model SwapChain

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5, directx-11

I'm working on an application using Qt 5.15.11 and ANGLE, which needs to play nice with another application out of my control. With a lot of experimentation with a small DirectX test app I determined that the problem can be fixed by using the Flip Model for the swap chain, e.g. like this:

```cpp
swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD;
```

Using PIX, I am relatively sure that my application is currently not using this SwapEffect, which is why it won't play nice.

I tried digging through the angle code, it seems that I need to set the attribute EGL_DIRECT_COMPOSITION_ANGLE to EGL_TRUE in order to enable this. That's where I'm stuck: I have no idea how to achieve this.

Can I get Qt and ANGLE to use this SwapEffect (or FLIP_SEQUENTIAL; I presume both work)? Will I need to recompile Qt or can it be done with an environment variable or other configuration method? I am currently stuck with Qt 5.15 but it's not entirely out of the question to upgrade to Qt 6 in the future.

Comment: EGL_DIRECT_COMPOSITION_ANGLE will enable DirectComposition with the side effect to force angle to use DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD, but it could have other side effects, are you sure the root reason of your problem is the chosen swapEffect? It seems a bit strange as many apps still use this and not many apps use DirectComposition. Otherwise you'll have to trace how your code (and Qt) ends up calling eglCreateWindowSurface or eglCreatePlatformWindowSurface as doc says to be able to pass the attribute

Comment: Thanks for your input. Our problem is rather obscure and it's hard to be sure. What I can be sure of is that a minimal directX 11 app was fixed by changing that one thing so I'd like to try this. Essentially, the "other" application is a remote desktop app which can cover the screen with a privacy shield but this currently freezes our GUI. We need to be able to (remote) control our app while the privacy screen is active. It seems, a "DirectX Proxy Window" is involved somehow, whatever that means!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's taken some time but we've gotten around to test this approach: Our problem was solved this way.

To answer this question, I'll provide what exactly I changed in Qt in order to enable this swap effect:

In /src/plugins/platforms/windows/qwindowseglcontext.cpp line I made the following change:

```cpp
 void *QWindowsEGLStaticContext::createWindowSurface(void *nativeWindow, void *nativeConfig, int *err)
 {
     *err = 0;
    EGLint attribs[3] = {
       EGL_DIRECT_COMPOSITION_ANGLE, EGL_TRUE,
       EGL_NONE
    };
    EGLSurface surface = libEGL.eglCreateWindowSurface(m_display, nativeConfig,
                            static_cast<EGLNativeWindowType>(nativeWindow), attribs); //attribs was nullptr before
```